# ReferenceError: document is not defined in Next.js while working with React Aria overlays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-aria

I'm learning Next.js for web development and I came across [commerce](https://github.com/vercel/commerce), a boilerplate for e-commerce websites written in Next.js. As I was browsing through the code I found the [`Sidebar` component](https://github.com/vercel/commerce/blob/19621632f57d67a5675037a777bfe3374cbaaebc/components/ui/Sidebar/Sidebar.tsx#L16) which uses [React Aria](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/index.html) for creating overlays.

I wanted to use this part in my own project, so wrote a `Overlay` component that also uses the `OverlayContainer` component.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';

import {
    useOverlay,
    useModal,
    OverlayContainer
} from '@react-aria/overlays';

const Overlay = ({ className, children, open = false, onClose }) => {
    const ref = useRef(null);

    const { modalProps } = useModal();

    let { overlayProps } = useOverlay({ onClose: onClose, open: open, isDismissable: true }, ref);
    return (
        <OverlayContainer>
            <div
                {...overlayProps}
                {...modalProps}
                ref={ref}
            >
                {children}
            </div>
        </OverlayContainer>

    );
};

export default Overlay;
```

This component gets loaded in my Layout component, just as in the [commerce project](https://github.com/vercel/commerce/blob/master/components/core/Layout/Layout.tsx#L70).
However, when I try to load up the index page, it gives me the following error:

> ```
> Server Error
> ReferenceError: document is not defined
>
> This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
> Source
> pages/_document.tsx (90:33) @ Function.getInitialProps
>
>   88 |     }
>   89 | 
> > 90 |     const { html, head } = await ctx.renderPage({ enhanceApp })
>      |                                 ^
>   91 |     const styles = [...flush()]
>   92 |     return { html, head, styles }
>   93 |   }
> ```

When I remove the `OverlayContainer` component, it loads all fine. I tried updating my dependencies, comparing more code to the Github repo, but nothing found so far.

What's the problem here? And how could I fix it? I'm using Next 10 with React 17.0.1.

Comment: You should read this: https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/ssr.html

Comment: I'm already  using the SSRProvider, just above the OverlayProvider :D

Comment: @Bas Could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround that you can do is `isBrowser` which is fairly common for NextJS apps.

`const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";`

Use it to conditionally render your `OverlayContainer`.

```
import { useRef } from "react";

import { useOverlay, useModal, OverlayContainer } from "@react-aria/overlays";

/**
 * Utility to detect if you're on the server, or in the browser.
 */
const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";

const Overlay = ({ className, children, open = false, onClose }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const { modalProps } = useModal();

  let { overlayProps } = useOverlay(
    { onClose: onClose, open: open, isDismissable: true },
    ref
  );
  return isBrowser ? (
    <OverlayContainer>
      <div {...overlayProps} {...modalProps} ref={ref}>
        {children}
      </div>
    </OverlayContainer>
  ) : null;
};

export default Overlay;
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the workaround of `const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined"` still retrieves an hydratation error.

Using useEffect and useState will fix that error.

```
const [isBrowser, setIsBrowser] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
 setIsBrowser(typeof window !== "undefined");
}, []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This should be the actual answer

Answer (score 1):

This happened because Next JS has server-side rendering. When you are using server-side rendering there is no browser. Hence, there is not any variable window or document. Hence this error shows up.